# How to share a global list with all processing in Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let's say I have the following code snippet:

```py
#imports

arr = [i for i in range(100000000)] #very large array

def f(x):
    a = 0
    for i in arr:
        a += i * x #sum each element * input value
    return a 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(f, [i for i in range(100)])
```

This would copy '*arr*' multiple times, taking up a lot of memory. Is there a way, using minimal modifications to the snippet above, to share '*arr*' across all processes (Read only)?

Comment: It's likely that your OS uses some variant of copy-on-write. Even though each process technically gets its own copy of the array, the OS won't actually allocate any new pages of memory unless a process tries to modify its copy.

Comment: @chepner My actual program (very similar to the one above, just with a list of Numpy arrays) will eat up all my RAM and page file (16GB RAM + ~30GB page) and crash half my programs. I'm not modifying the list (or arrays stored in the list) in any way, I'm just taking the values from the list, doing some processing, and returning completely different values. Might it be because I'm indexing the list, or passing a value from the list into a different function?

Comment: This feature may help [Python 3.8 introduced a new module multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://mingze-gao.com/posts/python-shared-memory-in-multiprocessing/) that provides shared memory for direct access across processes.

Comment: Lists and Numpy arrays are quite different. Please update your question to more closely match what actually produces the problem.

Comment: @DarrylG - sweeeet! Thank you.

Comment: @chepner different even if I just have a list of Numpy arrays?

Comment: @explodingfilms101 I don't know. But I'm not going to speculate without a reproducible example.

Comment: @chepner I don't think it matters if I have a list of integers or a list of Numpy arrays, since they'd both be stored in a list. So my question is not about Numpy arrays per-se, but about lists.

Comment: In response to comments above: Python will modify metadata on objects in a collection on access even if you're just reading them, causing the object to get copied to the sub-processes' memory. One reason for this is reference counting but I'm not sure if other modifications occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that uses shared memory. Even so, 100,000,000 integers is a lot of memory and will take a long time to initialize (I tested this with a considerably smaller size):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array

def init_pool(the_arr):
    global arr
    arr = the_arr

def f(x):
    a = 0
    for i in arr:
        a += i * x #sum each element * input value
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = Array('i', range(100_000_000), lock=False) # read/only, no locking required
    with Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(arr,)) as p:
        print(p.map(f, range(100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. You could break the map into chunks for reduced memory use (so that'd be loading and unloading *arr* for each call into that *i* SMP.

Or maybe the below - which is probably strictly frowned on but...

myGlobalVars.py

```
def initMyArr():

    #A foo to make a list
    global arr
    arr = [i for i in range(100000000)]

    return
```

myWorking.py

```
# -----------------------------------------------------
def f(x):
    import myGlobalVars  #Note - I think you might need to import here rather than at top of .py due to multiprocessing not carrying data down
    arr = myGlobalVars.arr
    a = 0
    for i in arr:
        a += i * x #sum each element * input value
    return a 


# -----------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import myGlobalVars
    #Call out to initialise the "global"
    myGlobalVars.initMyArr()

    #Then run your pool
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(f, [i for i in range(100)])
```

You could maybe do the same with a class variable, but not so sure on that.

edit: I'm going to put it here so its not lost in clutter - better to spend time looking into Gold_cy's approach or multiprocessing.shared_memory as suggested by DarrylG in comment to your question.

Comment: Would each process create a new 'arr' when it goes through f(x)?

Comment: It shouldn't given python's equivalence for variable mapping.

Comment: don't take this approach, use proper primitives instead like this --> https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array and example shown here --> https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: This does not solve the issue of each process in the pool having its own copy of  of `arr`. Moreover, with this arrangement your main process does not need to have a copy of `arr`  so why is it  even wastefully importing `myGlobalVars` and calling `initMyArr` creating one extra, unnecessary copy?

Comment: Using "=" (and not copy.deepcopy) should only remap to the actual location in memory. So it shouldn't be duplicating the memory used. Each processes won't, or shouldn't have its own *copy*, but instead have its own *copy* of a link to where the actual data is stored.

Comment: First, when you are posting a question tagged with `multiprocessing` you are supposed to tag the question additionally with the platform you are running under, such as `Windows` or `Linux`, which you didn't. It appears that you are running under Windows. Each process is created with its own empty address space and a new Python interpreter is launched to re-execute the source from the top. It cannot "see" any variables that are in the main process's address space but must initialize its own address space with the data *unless the data itself is in shared memory*.

Comment: Pardon me (I should have had that second cup of coffee).